# How do I change the line color for a part of scatterPlot by using core plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I want to know how to change the line color for a part of scatter plot by using core plot on iPhone project.
   E.g. if the currently value of Y axis > the previous value, then the line color change to red, otherwise the line color keep to green. Below is my code, but I found the color not change for a part of plot, that change to the whole plot. :( 
  appreciate if anyone can give some suggestion.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

{

```
CPTScatterPlot *myPlot = (CPTScatterPlot *)plot;
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineWidth              = 3.f;
lineStyle.dashPattern            = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f], nil];

NSLog(@"index: %d",index);


if(index < 7 && index > 0 && fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY){
if ([[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] floatValue] > [[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index-1] floatValue]) {
    //lineStyle.lineColor                = [CPTColor redColor];
    NSLog(@"%f > %f",[[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] floatValue],[[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index-1] floatValue]);
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    myPlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

}else {
    lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor greenColor];
    myPlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
}
}




if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX){
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
}else if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY){
    return [dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index];
}
}
```

Comment: hi.. i am also having the same requirement...have u got the solution???
thank u...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported right now. You have to use a different plot for each color/line style that you want to use.

Comment: @Eric Skroch I have updated the answer to this question. Please correct it if needed.Thanks.